# How to use gdbserver with LD_PRELOAD for debugee

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver, ld-preload

I'm trying to debug the program remotely with gdbserver.

The following works fine:

```
gdbserver :1234 ./test-program
```

But I need to debug the program with preloaded .so file.
And this doesn't work:

```
gdbserver :1234 'LD_PRELOAD=./libefence.so ./test-program'
```

How to do this?

Tried also to use exec wrapper, but this doesn't work either:

```
gdbserver --wrapper 'LD_PRELOAD=./libefence.so' -- :1234 ./test-program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
gdbserver --wrapper env 'LD_PRELOAD=./libefence.so' -- :1234 ./test-program
```